# `sp_io::crypto::ed25519_batch_verify` was removed amid Polkadot 0.9.39 and 0.9.43. What is replacement in Runtime?

Tags: runtime, cryptography, host-functions

We used`ed25519_batch_verify` in runtime from `sp_io::crypto` mod.

`sp_io::Crypto and Verify` traits require `self`, but I cannot find implementation.

In substrate primitives core I see verify  calling

```
    fn verify<M: AsRef<[u8]>>(sig: &Signature, message: M, public: &Public) -> bool {
        let Ok(public) = VerificationKey::try_from(public.as_slice()) else { return false };
        let Ok(signature) = ed25519_zebra::Signature::try_from(sig.as_ref()) else { return false };
        public.verify(&signature, message.as_ref()).is_ok()
    }
```

but does it call host functions for perfromance?

UPDATE:

```
# This feature enables all crypto primitives for `no_std` builds like microcontrollers
# or Intel SGX.
# For the regular wasm runtime builds this should not be used.
full_crypto = [
    ...
    "ed25519-zebra",
    ...
]
```

So that code not to be used in Runtime.